# Moved to the 5 GHz band but my old devices don't see it

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router

With the 2.4 GHz band totally cluttered and delivering worst speeds, I went ahead and bought a (5 GHz) dual band router. But the problem is that my older devices like a Vizio TV and an Android TV box do not see the 5 GHz band. I understand that their network cards are limited to 2.4 GHz. What alternatives can I use to either improve the speed of my 2.4 GHz router or make my older devices see the 5 GHz band? (Maybe by buying a 5 GHz wireless USB adapter for the TV and the Android box?)

Model - Asus RT-N66U

SSID 1 - 2.4 GHz - 802.11n

SSID 2 - 5   GHz - 802.11n

More information about my situation: My devices see only the 2.4 GHz band and not the other one. And I want my devices to use the 5 GHz band instead because when they connect to 2.4 GHz band the speed drops down to <2 Mbps whereas on the 5 GHz band, they are showing the actual speed of ~90 Mbps (105 Mbps plan).

Comment: What makes you say the 2.4ghz band is crowded?

Lots of other 2.4ghz networks in the area (apartment/dorm building?), interference from wireless phones and the like?

Comment: Also, if you have a 2.4ghz router, is it B, G, or N?
How many devices are on the 2.4ghz wireless at one time?

Comment: Please [edit] and include the model of the router.  The most likely scenario is you have a dual band router, but the 2.4Ghz is set to N only and you need G (or that the 2.4Ghz is turned off).

Comment: @astv25 The speed is pathetic and I verified that the 2.4 Ghz is crowded with at least 20 other networks. The 2.4 & 5 Ghz bands both show that they are 802.11n.

Comment: @Paul How do I change it from n to g ? I don't see any option in the settings.

Comment: You could always try to change the channel the 2.4ghz network broadcasts on.

That'd at least help with the clutter on the 2.4 band.  Possibly the speed issue as well, though the speed could also be affected by the number of devices on the network.

Comment: @deppfx It is usually called "mixed mode" in the settings.  Everyone is just guessing until you [edit] and add the router model.

Comment: @Paul Sorry. I added it in the question itself but missed mentioning it here.

Comment: This is akin to asking if you can listen to 88.5 FM in English by dialing to a spanish-language station on 103.3 FM, and only knowing Spanish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can I make my older devices see the 5GHz band?

No. Because your older devices are using hardware that only can connect to 2.4GHz 802.11 networks. You also cannot purchase USB 802.11 devices for phones and smart TVs.

> Maybe by buying a 5 GHz wireless USB adapter for the TV and the
>   Android box?

If you willing to buy hardware. The simplest solution would be to purchase a 2.4 GHz single-band router and connect it to the 5 GHz router.

> I went ahead and bought a (5 GHz) dual band router.

Since the Asus RT-N66U actually is a dual-band router. It should be as simply as turning on the 2.4 radio in the configuration page.

The type of devices you want to connect to 5 GHz cannot connect, and getting additional hardware to add that capability is silly if all you have to do is enable the other network on the router (which is likely disabled by default).

Comment: If you can show me a consumer simultaneous dual-band (but not so-called "tri-band") router where both networks can do 5 GHz, I'll be impressed. I don't think such a thing actually exists, so I don't think it's a likely possibility. Every box I've seen that can do two 5GHz networks is "tri-band": one on 2.4GHz, two on 5GHz.

Comment: @ramhound Do you think connecting a 2.4 Ghz to the parent 5 Ghz band separates the child 2.4 Ghz (connected to the parent 5Ghz band) from the clutter existing 2.4 Ghz networks clutter ? I guess it won't make a difference since the branching child 2.4 Ghz again becomes a part of the existing noisy 2.4 Ghz networks.

Comment: @deppfx - Of course it doesn't.  Any interference that exists on 2.4Ghz band will still exist.  The `Asus RT-N66U` has two radios, which broadcast at two different frequencies, which means they are independant of one another.  You just have to enable the second radio its likely turned off by default.

Comment: @qasdfdsaq - I appreciate the revenge downvote.

Answer (score 3):

Most 5GHz routers can broadcast on both the 5GHz and 2.4GHz frequencies simultaneously.

Check your wireless router manual. This is often called “Simultaneous Dual Band”, or “Dual Band Concurrent”.

Comment: Honestly I wouldn't say most routers are dual band routers most are not.  Most are single band routers that are extremely cheap and honestly actually have horrible firmware running on them.

Comment: I think most 5GHz routers are dual-band routers.

Comment: Of course, my router is dual band. My devices see only the 2.4 Ghz band and not the other one. And I want my devices to use the 5 Ghz band instead because when they connect to 2.4 Ghz band the speed drops down to <2 Mbps whereas on the 5 Ghz band, they are showing the actual speed of ~90 Mbps (105 Mbps plan). Yes, that's how bad it is.

Comment: @deppfx Not all devices support both 2.4 and 5ghz. If the device doesn't see the 5ghz band, then it is likely a hardware limitation. Nothing you can do.

Comment: @spuder I understand that part but I am looking for solutions like the one [Ramhound](http://superuser.com/a/917999/124651) suggested like connecting a 2.4 Ghz router to the 5Ghz. I'm not sure if that separates the child 2.4 Ghz (connected to the parent 5Ghz band) from the clutter. I'm waiting for his views on that.

Comment: @deppfx You already have a 2.4ghz router, and they are already 'connected'. Buying a second router won't help. If the devices don't have 5ghz antennas, then they will never be able to see it. That is why hardware manufactures made dual band routers, so that non compatible devices could still get wifi.

Answer (score -1):

ATT is now using the newer dual band router with 2.4 and 5.0  model 5268ac

adsl and vdsl Like you mine only sees 2.4 even my new iPad its there but there is no way to flip them or to get them to work on older systems. To answer the other users question I bought a USB Belkin to put in the side of of my one year old HP laptop but no success still 2.4.